# morris chart does not work on firefox

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, raphael, morris.js

Hello I am working on a app that displays morris chart on bootstrap tab. The Graphs are displayed on firefox but does not show in firefox or Internet explorer.

Please help.

Here is the Java scrip code that i am using:

```
$('ul.nav a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
  var types = $(this).attr("data-identifier");
  var typesArray = types.split(",");
  $.each(typesArray, function(key, value) {
    eval(value + ".redraw()");
  })
});
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('data.php', function(json) {
    var areac = {
      element: 'revenue-chart',
      data: Object.keys(json.qa).map(function(key) {
        return json.qa[key];
      }),
      xkey: 'audit_date',
      ykeys: ['audit_score'],
      labels: ['QA Score'],
      lineColors: ['#a0d0e0', '#3c8dbc'],
      hideHover: 'auto'
    };
    line = Morris.Line(areac)
      //Donut Chart
    var area1 = {
      element: 'sales-chart',
      data: Object.keys(json.ecsat).map(function(key) {
        return json.ecsat[key];
      }),
      xkey: 'csat_date',
      ykeys: ['csat_score'],
      labels: ['CSAT Score'],
      hideHover: 'auto'
    };
    line1 = Morris.Area(area1)
  });

});
```

[Here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/eshanan/a3ue9wbx/2/)

Here is the result from data.php

{"qa":[{"audit_date":"2014-10-23","audit_score":"92"},{"audit_date":"2014-10-16","audit_score":"67"},{"audit_date":"2014-10-01","audit_score":"90"},{"audit_date":"2014-10-03","audit_score":"96"},{"audit_date":"2014-10-05","audit_score":"75"},{"audit_date":"2014-10-20","audit_score":"89"}],"ecsat":[{"csat_score":"2.0000","csat_date":"2014-10-05"},{"csat_score":"3.7500","csat_date":"2014-10-12"},{"csat_score":"2.0667","csat_date":"2014-10-19"},{"csat_score":"1.6250","csat_date":"2014-10-26"},{"csat_score":"1.0000","csat_date":"2014-11-02"}],"pcsat":[{"pcsat_score":"10.0000","pcsat_date":"2014-10-19"},{"pcsat_score":"10.0000","pcsat_date":"2014-11-02"}]}

Comment: The same code works great when using Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caued as bootstrap tabs hide div's i was trying to draw my charts on.

Added a code to check if the div is active before drawing my graph:

```
$('ul.nav a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
        if ($(e.target).attr('href') == '#tab-name' && $('#tab-name').html().length == 0) 
{
<<---Draw chart here --->>
}
});
```